# How can I count the values in a column to use it to define a variable and how can I display a url as a hyperlink (text) using Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, count, hyperlink

I've developed the below script (with the help of existing scripts in stackoverflow) and it does what it is intended to do. There are 2 things I want to change in the script but not sure how.

1- Instead of reading the value in a cell where I do a count of values, I want to count the values in the script

2- In the email I send out, I want to display a hyperlink text instead of the url.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
function sendEmails() {
  //enter the sheet name
  var sheetname = 'CFS Open Cases Report' 
  var counter_sheet = 'count of recipients'
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);

  //A1 is the cell that counts the number of rows in Column A. Try counting values in A2:A in the script instead
  var row_counter = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(counter_sheet).getRange("A2"); 
  var row_count = row_counter.getValue();
 

  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = row_count;   // Number of rows to process

  //find a way to display the url as a hyperlink in the email body
  var report_url = "https://google.com";

 
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:D 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var first_name = row[0]; // First column
    var emailAddress = row[3]; // Fourth column
    
    //html message text
    var msgHtml = 'message and' + report_url
    ; 
    //today's date to be used as report date
    var report_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var report_desc = "Report Name"
    var subject = report_date +' - '+ report_desc; 

            
    //send the email
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, msgHtml);
  }
}
```

**Here's the modified script:**

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheetname = 'Sheet1' // enter the sheet name where the recipient details are listed
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var row_count = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(String).length; // counts the rows in the A2:A range
  var startRow = 2; // first row of data to process
  var numRows =　row_count; // number of rows to process
      
  var report_url = "www.google.com";    


  // Fetch the range of cells A2:D 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var first_name = row[0]; // First column
    var emailAddress = row[3]; // Fourth column
    
    //html message text
    var msgHtml = 'Hi ' + first_name +',' 
    + '<br/><br/>message here.'
    + '<br/><br/>more message here.'
    + '<br/><br/>and more: '+ '<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>'
    + '<br/><br/>Kind Regards,'
    + '<br/><br/>my name'
    ; 
    //today's date to be used as report date
    var report_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var report_desc = "CFS Open Cases Report"
    var subject = report_date +' - '+ report_desc; 

    // clear html tags and convert br to new lines for plain mail    
    var msgPlain = msgHtml.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""); 
    
    //send the email
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, msgPlain);
  }
}
```

**Here's where I'm stuck with. I need to get rid of the html tags but keep the line breaks before I send the emails out:**

```
var msgHtml = 'Hi ' + first_name +',' 
    + '<br/><br/>second line.'
    + '<br/><br/>third line.'
    + '<br/><br/>fourth line ' + `<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>`
    + '<br/><br/>fifth line,'
    + '<br/><br/>sixth line'
    ;    

    //today's date to be used as report date
    var report_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var report_desc = "CFS Open Cases Report"
    var subject = report_date +' - '+ report_desc; 

    // clear html tags and convert br to new lines for plain mail    
    var msgPlain = msgHtml.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""); 
    
    //send the email
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, msgHtml); 
  }
```

**Finally understood what was wrong:**

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, msgHtml);
```

**Changed the above to and it works now:**

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailAddress, subject: subject, htmlBody: msgHtml});
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Instead of reading the value in a cell where I do a count of values, I want to count the values in the script`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, it's probably my English apologies. So, I want to count the values in a column in the spreadsheet where I have the names and email addresses of the recipients. I want to count the number of the recipients using app script. Currently, I am doing a counta(A2:A) in the sheet and using that value in the script. Hope it's clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `Instead of reading the value in a cell where I do a count of values, I want to count the values in the script`, in order to covert `counta(A2:A)` to Google Apps Script, I thought that `var row_count = counter_sheet_obj.getRange("A2:A" + counter_sheet_obj.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(String).length;` might be useful.
- About `In the email I send out, I want to display a hyperlink text instead of the url.`, in order to send an email including the hyperlink of `report_url`, I thought that `htmlBody` can be used. For this, I modified `var msgHtml = 'message and' + report_url` to `var msgHtml = 'message and ' +` ${report_url}`;`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var sheetname = 'CFS Open Cases Report'
  var counter_sheet = 'count of recipients'
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var counter_sheet_obj = ss.getSheetByName(counter_sheet);
  var row_count = counter_sheet_obj.getRange("A2:A" + counter_sheet_obj.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(String).length;
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows =　row_count;
  var report_url = "https://google.com";
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var first_name = row[0]; // This is not used in your script.
    var emailAddress = row[3];
    var msgHtml = 'message and ' + `<a href="${report_url}">${report_url}</a>`;
    var report_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var report_desc = "Report Name"
    var subject = report_date + ' - ' + report_desc;
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailAddress, subject: subject, htmlBody: msgHtml});
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(message) of Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

### Added:

When I saw your current script, I think that you don't correctly reflect my proposed script. Please modify your current script as follows.

#### From:

```
+ '<br/><br/>and more: '+ '<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>'
```

#### To:

```
+ '<br/><br/>and more: '+ `<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>`
```

- Please use `` ` `` instead of `'`.

#### Reference:

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tanaike! It resolved my first issue. However, the hyperlink did not work as I wanted it to be. What I want to be able to do it is  to display a hyperlink like "Go to Google" instead of displaying www.google.com in the email body. Can you help with this one too? Really appreciated!

Comment: @arda0910 Thank you for replying. About `However, the hyperlink did not work as I wanted it to be. What I want to be able to do it is to display a hyperlink like "Go to Google" instead of displaying www.google.com in the email body.`, in that case, how about modifying ``var msgHtml = 'message and ' + `<a href="${report_url}">${report_url}</a>`;`` to ``var msgHtml = 'message and ' + `<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>`;`` in my proposed script?

Comment: it now changes the text in the email to Go to Google, however, I need "Go to Google" to be a hyperlink that will take the recipient to www.google.com when clicked. Thanks so much for trying to resolve this and apologies for keep asking for more.

Comment: @arda0910 Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I need "Go to Google" to be a hyperlink that will take the recipient to www.google.com when clicked.`. In this case, ``var msgHtml = 'message and ' + `<a href="https://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>`;`` is the result you expect? If I misunderstood your additional question, can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: thanks once again. When I run the code as you shared, "Go to Google" appears as a text in the emails sent out. I want "Go to Google" to be a hyperlink in the email which will direct you to www.google.com when clicked on. So, I want the report_url in my email to be part of the email body but instead of displaying to whole url, I want it to appear as a hyperlink. Is it clear now? Thanks again for your time and efforts.

Comment: @arda0910 Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that ``var msgHtml = 'message and ' + `<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>`;`` is the result you expect. And, in this case, please set the URL you expect to `report_url`. For example, when `report_url` is `https://www.google.com`, that is [Go to Google](https://www.google.com). How about this?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. So my report_url variable is equals the url https://www.google.com already. If I do `var msgHtml = 'message' + report_url` , the value set for this variable which is https://www.google.com appears in the email body. And yes, this is what is does as expected. However, I want it to appear as Go to Google. (with a hyperlink that will take you google.com).  Can you explain what you mean here please: _For example, when report_url is https://www.google.com, that is Go to Google. How about this?_ Thank you!

Comment: @arda0910 Thank you for replying. For your replying, I think that `var msgHtml = 'message and ' + `<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>`;` can work for your goal. In this case, when you see the HTML mail, you can see message and [Go to Google](https://www.google.com). Can I ask you about the issue of this modification? And, in order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the current script including my proposed modified script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @arda0910 When you add your current script, please add it to your question. Because you posted your current script as an answer. And, when I saw your current script, I think that you don't correctly reflect my proposed script. For this, I added the modification point in my answer. Could you please confrim it?

Comment: that's done. Apologies.

Comment: that's done, apologies. @Tanaike, I've tried ``+ '<br/><br/>and more: '+ `<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>`` but, in the email I still see "Go to Google" as a text, not an hyperlink. Note: I can't seem to add the last ``` in the comments for some reason but as you can see it's in the code. Thanks!

Comment: @arda0910 Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that the reason of your current issue is to use `msgPlain` as the text body. When you want to use the hyperlink, please use the HTML body. So I had proposed to use the HTML body in my answer. I apologize for this.

Comment: thanks again for your time and help. So, when I use the `msgHtml` as the email body, this is how is appears in the email: _<a 
href="www.google.com">Go 
to Google</a>_. So, the html tags remain in the email when I use the  `msgHtml` instead of `msgPlain` and also it still shows both the whole url (www.google.com) and "Go to Google" and "Go to Google" is not a hyperlink, but it's just plain text. When you run the code, do you see only Go to Google as a hyperlink?

Comment: @arda0910 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When you use my proposed modified script, the HTML body is sent. For this, when ``var msgHtml = 'message and ' + `<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>`;`` is used instead of ``var msgHtml = 'message and ' + `<a href="${report_url}">${report_url}</a>`;``, the text with the hyperlink is used. How about this?

Comment: thanks. So, when I use the `var msgHtml = 'message and ' + ``<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>`; ` this is the output: _<a 
href="www.google.com">Go to Google_. When I use var `msgHtml = 'message and ' + ``<a href="${report_url}">${report_url}</a>`;` output is: _<a 
href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>_ . Both examples I sent the email body as `msgHtml`. When I use `msgPlain`, the output is the same but the html tags are removed. So, I never get Go to Google as a hyperlink in the output. Thanks!

Comment: @arda0910 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. At first, can you test my proposed script? Because when I saw your current script, your script doesn't correctly reflect my proposed script. When I tested my proposed script, the text with the hyperlink can be seen. I apologize for this. At that time, please modify ``var msgHtml = 'message and ' + `<a href="${report_url}">Go to Google</a>`;``.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, your code works as expected. I guess the reason why not my code is working is because of the html tags, line breaks I'm using. When I remove them in `msgPlain`, it causes the hyperlink to not work. I've edited my question and kindly ask you to have a look at it and modify that. I need the line breaks so that the email body is formatted properly. Thanks a lot for your time and patience in resolving this.

Comment: I realised what was different in my code! Apologies, it's not fixed and is working. Thanks a lot for your help and patience! I updated your response as "accepted". Thanks!

Comment: @arda0910 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.